# #1062 - Duplicate entry '81057' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am not fluent in using phpmyadmin so please be gentle.

I have transferred wordpress sites in the past but they have small databases.  Ive now moved a new clients site to my hosting and it is running with this error:

```
INSERT INTO  `wp_options`  VALUES ( 81057, 
'_wc_session_6f1ee0a5a9d89e47f7941c9e3b3e1fed',
'a:20:{s:4:"cart";s:309:"a:1:{s:32:"7b1ce3d73b70f1a7246e7b76a35fb552";a:9:{s:10:"product_id";i:2103;s:12:"variation_id";s:0:"";s:9:"variation";s:0:"";s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:10:"line_total";d:23;s:8:"line_tax";i:0;s:13:"line_subtotal";d:23;s:17:"line_subtotal_tax";i:0;s:13:"line_tax_data";a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}}}";s:15:"applied_coupons";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:23:"coupon_discount_amounts";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:19:"cart_contents_total";d:23;s:20:"cart_contents_weight";i:0;s:19:"cart_contents_count";i:1;s:17:"cart_contents_tax";i:0;s:5:"total";i:0;s:8:"subtotal";d:23;s:15:"subtotal_ex_tax";d:23;s:9:"tax_total";i:0;s:5:"taxes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:14:"shipping_taxes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:13:"discount_cart";i:0;s:14:"discount_total";i:0;s:14:"shipping_total";i:0;s:18:"shipping_tax_total";i:0;s:9:"fee_total";i:0;s:4:"fees";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:10:"wc_notices";N;}',
no' ) ;`

#1062 - Duplicate entry '81057' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I genuinely do not have a clue what this means and how to change it.  I get that there is a duplicate entry and its to do with the primary key - which is set on option_id.

What i don't get is why it doesn't just add the entries into the database and auto increment them - which it is set to do? Also how can i resolve the issue and add the database?

please help !

Comment: It won't use an autoincrement key, because you're specifically telling it to use the key value `81057` in your insert statement

Comment: it stated clearly that you want to insert a record with id `81057`, which is already exist.Since your `id` column is primary key so it refuses this second (duplicate) entry.

Comment: the error-message is clear *Duplicate* *81057* ... do a research of table, indexing and the meaning of PRIMARY KEYS

Answer (score 0):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` is a **default** value. If you specify a value for the field it will be used instead.

You can omit the value in the insert statement or use NULL instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the table in your source database has some inconsistency since you are only trying to copy all records to your new database.
Check if there are multiple records with same `option_id` in your source table and if there are some try to resolve them and then try the import again.

As i understand you are trying to do the manual transfer of the whole database and in that case `AUTO_INCREMENT` just wont work since you will break the relations between your model entities.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you have two options.

1. Omit the primary key value and allow mysql to create a new row and auto increment it. Of course this will require you to specify the columns.

   ```
   INSERT INTO  `wp_options`(column2, column3, etc)
   VALUES('_wc_session_6f1ee0a5a9d89e47f7941c9e3b3e1fed', ...);
   ```

> Notice that I left out the primary key

2. If the data needs to be added to that specific row, do an `UPDATE` instead.

   ```
   UPDATE wp_options SET column2='_wc_session_6f1ee0a5a9d89e47f7941c9e3b3e1fed', 
   column3='something else', ...
   WHERE column1=81057
   ```